# adding a slider under each item in array with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

`

```js
var data = { Name: "Test",
    Items: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3","DESIGN"]      
};

function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.saved = ko.observable(false);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items, function(item) {
        return { value: ko.observable(item) };
    }));
                                    
    self.addItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.removeItem = function(data) { 
        self.Items.remove(data);
    };
    
     self.SaveItem = function() { self.Items.push({ value: ko.observable("") }); };
    self.SaveItem = function(data) { 
         //self.Items.save(data); 
         self.saved(true);
    };
}
$(document).ready(function() {ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
                             
            $("#slider").slider();                 
                             
                             });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Items: <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: Items }"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <button data-bind="click: SaveItem">SAVE</button>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="visible: !$parent.saved()">
            <input data-bind="value: value" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">X</a>
        </td>
       <td data-bind="visible: $parent.saved()">
            <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I have an items in an array using knockout.js   The issue I am facing is when these items are saved, I have it coded to display a slider under each item. It only displays under one. Can someone explain why its not displaying under all of them using the view below??

Comment: It's not valid to have multiple items with the same `id`. My guess is you're using jQuery to attach a slider to that div, hoping it will attach to all, but finding elements by id only finds one.

Comment: ok, i show a full sample. Yes, I am using jQuery to attach the slider to the div and it only displays under the first one. I am guessing I need to bind it to all of them. I tried using a span, but that does not work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I give you code to do what you're trying to do: identify the divs using the class attribute, selecting by that, and making the jQuery UI slider call on each. I give you this solution because you are clearly just learning, and this is kind of a basic tool.

**However, this is not a good approach to building an application with Knockout.**

In Knockout, you will not use jQuery to pull pieces of the DOM and manipulate them unless you are writing a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), which would be the correct way to apply a slider widget. If you have not yet gone through the [Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com), I urge you to do so. Then read about custom binding handlers at the link above and [also here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).

Learning by experimentation has its place, but it's better to build up basic knowledge from more structured presentations.

```js
var data = {
  Name: "Test",
  Items: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "DESIGN"]
};

function ViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.saved = ko.observable(false);
  self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items, function(item) {
    return {
      value: ko.observable(item)
    };
  }));

  self.addItem = function() {
    self.Items.push({
      value: ko.observable("")
    });
  };
  self.removeItem = function(data) {
    self.Items.remove(data);
  };

  self.SaveItem = function() {
    self.Items.push({
      value: ko.observable("")
    });
  };
  self.SaveItem = function(data) {
    //self.Items.save(data); 
    self.saved(true);
  };
}
$(document).ready(function() {
      ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));

      $(".slider").each(function() {
        $(this).slider();
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Items:
  <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: Items }"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: SaveItem">SAVE</button>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="visible: !$parent.saved()">
      <input data-bind="value: value" />
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">X</a>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="visible: $parent.saved()">
      <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
      <div class="slider"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```